# How to alert something already on screen in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am working in beamer and I would like to write this equation in one slide:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{equation}
\delta {S} = \int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left[\delta g^{\alpha\beta} \left( G_{\alpha\beta} + \kappa T_{\alpha\beta}\right)
+g^{\alpha\beta} \delta R_{\alpha\beta}\right]=0.
\end{equation}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

And having the term `g^{\alpha\beta} \delta R_{\alpha\beta}`, alerted in the next slide.

I was thinking of just copying the frame, with the eqn alerted, but then it would be counted as a new slide right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! You can use `\alert` with an overlay specification, e.g. `\alert<2>{<stuff>}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{equation}
\delta {S} = \int\!\mathsf{d}^4x\,\sqrt{-g}\left[
\delta g^{\alpha\beta} \left( G_{\alpha\beta} + \kappa T_{\alpha\beta}\right)
+\alert<2>{g^{\alpha\beta} \delta R_{\alpha\beta}}\right]=0.
\end{equation}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I had to put ```alert<3>```, since I had already a ```\pause``` on the slide.